# Pandas how to group rows with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multiple-columns

I want to group two columns together, but only if a specific column is not null, here is some Sudo code for my idea. I'm not sure if this is possible in pandas.

```
if(df[food] != null):
df['food'].groupby(df['time']).agg('sum')
```

I was thinking maybe something with NumPy

```
df['food'].groupby(df['time']).agg('sum').np(where .....
```

Comment: when you take the sum, Null values are not counted anyways. So, you don't need to check if Fruits is Null or not

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have any data example so I took an example database from plotly.

```
data=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
```

If I want to group the 'AAPL.High' and 'AAPL.Low' columns together, but only if the 'AAPL.Volume' column is not null, the code should be like the following try:

```
data['AAPL.High'].groupby(data['AAPL.Volume'].notnull()).sum()
```

Lemme know if that helps!